# Populating a listbox from database with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ado.net

I'm developing a .NET application, and I have a problem.
I try to populate a listbox from a MySQL database with Entity Framework.
Here is my code:

```
public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            try
            {
                hospitaldbEntities context = new hospitaldbEntities();
                PatientlistBoxId.DataSource = context.patients;
                PatientlistBoxId.DisplayMember = "FirstName";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
```

I attach a picture from the Solution Explorer:
[image]

And finally here is my patient class:

```
public partial class patient
    {
        public patient()
        {
            this.examinations = new HashSet<examination>();
            this.diseases = new HashSet<disease>();
            this.drugsensitivities = new HashSet<drugsensitivity>();
        }

        public int PatientID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateOfCreate { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public int CNP { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<examination> examinations { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<disease> diseases { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<drugsensitivity> drugsensitivities { get; set; }
    }
```

Thank you for the help in advance.

**EDIT**

When I try to run the application, it throws an error:
[image]

Comment: what's happening? Some error?

Comment: I added some more details.

Comment: The exception tells you *exactly* what to to.

Answer (score 1):

You must at least use:

```
PatientlistBoxId.DataSource = context.patients.ToList();
```

Consider using a [BindingList<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

BTW:

Consider not using an Entity type as ItemType for the ListBox.

Consider using a `using` context to dispose your context, that is handle more clearly the scope of your context.

========== ==========

A little bit more details

```
//this class allows to separate the winform (equivalent to a view) from 
//the data layer, you can see it as a ViewModel
public class FormNamePatient {
    public Int32 Id { get; set;}
    public String FirstName { get; set;}
    public String LastName { get; set;}
}

private BindingList<FormNamePatient> _patients;
try {
   //the using guarantees the disposing of the resources 
   //(avoiding memory link and so on)
   using ( hospitaldbEntities context = new hospitaldbEntities() ) {
       _patients = new BindindList<FormNamePatient>(
           context.patients.Select(
              x => new FormNamePatient {
                  Id = x.Id,
                  FirstName = x.FirstName,
                  LastName = x.LastName,
              }).ToList() // this materialize the list
                          // in other (bad ?) words, this allows the list
                          //to live out of the context (<=> using)
       );       
   }
   PatientlistBoxId.DataSource ) = _patients;
   //now if you alter (not erase, but edit, change...) _patients you 
   //update the control
   PatientlistBoxId.DisplayMember = "FirstName";
} catch (Exception ex) {
  Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

Comment: +1 for BindingList - there is even [extension for that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696575(v=vs.103).aspx). Usage: context.patients.Local.ToBindingList();  [More details on .Local and .ToBindingList()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592872.aspx)

Comment: Could you explain me a little bit more detailed with code exactly what to do, because I haven't much experience with .NET. Thanks in advance.